# Performing Key Output from C# to EuroTruck not working (PostMessage, user32.dll)

Tags: c#, keyboard, postmessage, user32

I am trying to get my C# script to output into ets2 so that it will drive for me (wasd). For testing I am using the space bar. I have tested the code in chrome and notepad, where it works and puts down a space. Would anyone know what is going wrong?

Update:
I wrote a little bit of test code for python using the keyboard module and I got it to work. Would it be possible to make "space" into a variable that I could change from C#?

Python Code:

```
import keyboard, time
time.sleep(5)
keyboard.press_and_release("space")
```

The Threads and Windows in Spy++:

[image]
[image]

I use the following code:

```
    public const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
    const int VK_SPACE = 0x20;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000); // gives user time to switch tabs
        IntPtr programloc = WindowHelper.GetForegroundWindow();
        // I also tried using (from Spy++) FindWindow("Euro Truck Simulator 2", "prism3d");
        if (programloc == IntPtr.Zero) throw new SystemException();
        WindowHelper.PostMessage(programloc, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_SPACE, 0);
    }
```

and the following module WindowHelper (combination of multiple Stackoverflow and docs.microsoft pages):

```
class WindowHelper
{
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(
        string lpClassName,
        string lpWindowName);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(
                IntPtr hwndParent,
                IntPtr hwndChildAfter,
                string lpszClass,
                string lpszWindos);

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg, int wParam, string lParam);

    [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
    public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetForegroundWindow")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to find a (temporary) fix myself. This fix is however not very performance friendly. Anyone having better suggestions is welcome.

Using the keyboard function I described in my question, I made a python script which uses arguments. This python script is started by the C# script using the following code:

```
static public string run_python(string cmd, string args)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
        start.FileName = @"C:\Users\Stijn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe";
        start.Arguments = string.Format("\"{0}\" \"{1}\"", cmd,args);
        start.UseShellExecute = false;// Do not use OS shell
        start.CreateNoWindow = true; // We don't need new window
        start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;// Any output, generated by application will be redirected back
        start.RedirectStandardError = true; // Any error in standard output will be redirected back (for example exceptions)
        using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
            {
                string stderr = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd(); // Here are the exceptions from our Python script
                string result = reader.ReadToEnd(); // Here is the result of StdOut(for example: print "test")
                return result + stderr;
            }
        }
    }
```

The python code consists of:

```
from keyboard import press_and_release
from sys import argv as args
for i in range(len(args)-1):
    press_and_release(args[i+1])
```

Using the keyboard module as can be found at https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/

Answer (score -1):

Your code is exiting immediately. Is this intentional? Make a call to Console.Readline() at the end of main to block until you give the console input.

Comment: I will try this, but the code showed on the site is a simplified version, where I have removed a lot of the unnecessary code. For example, a Windows Form is also started after trying to press the spacebar. Therefore it does not terminate very quickly after having tried to press the spacebar.